# Spring Integration JAVA DSL Using original payload in a subsequent call

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

I am using spring integration to define a flow that will do two things - firstly execute http call with given payload and then use the response provided and original payload to make another http call.

How can this be achieved? In the code below I am able to use and modify the first payload and use it in the firstHttpRequest but then how can I use the original payload with the response from the firstHttpRequest?

Any good practices?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow makeHttpCalls(){

    return message -> message               
             .transform(new GenericTransformer<Message<String>, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String transform(Message<String> message){
                            return message.getPayload() + " first call";    
                    }    
             })
             .handle(makeFirstHttpRequest())
             .transform(new GenericTransformer<Message<String>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String transform(Message<String> message) {
                    logger.debug("Response from transform: " + message);
                    return message.getPayload();
                }
             }) 
            .handle(makeSecondHttpRequest())
            .channel("entrypoint");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is `.enrichHeaders()` and place that original `payload` into one custom header. Therefore downstream, after response, get deal with that header to restore an original `payload`.

Another approach is `.enrich()` when you make an external call and enrich original message with info from reply.

There is other tools, like `.routeToRecipients()` and `.publishSubscribeChannel()` where you send the same message to different sub-flows for different logics.

But that's it what you have to choose.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about using using .enrichHeaders() and populating a header isn't really the best approach as it will use that custom header in the http call.
Where exactly would .enrich() have to be used? Before making the http call?

Comment: ??? The `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` doesn't map custom headers. Need to understand your `makeFirstHttpRequest()` definition.

Comment: This is the Handler that I am using to make a call:
`Http.outboundGateway(FIRST_CALL_URI).extractPayload(true).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).expectedResponseType(String.class).get();`
should I use a different one?

Comment: No, that's fine. Not sure than what you mean with the "will use that custom header in the http call". Please, elaborate.

Comment: Have just tested it locally `.enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("foo", "bar")).handleWithAdapter(a ->a.httpGateway(...))` and I don't see that `foo` header in the HTTP header for request.

Comment: Thanks that's working fine. 
A side question wow would you pass a custom header to the http call in this case?

Comment: I won't pass, because I know that other side isn't interested in it. But since I would like to deal with it afterwards, I'm glad that reply message carries it for me